# Problem with a function that shuffles and squares an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

I'm trying to write a function that will randomize the order of the elements in the array and also square those elements. I managed to write it with two parameters, however I want to write it using only one parameter but for some reason I always get weird values as solutions. Sometimes they are correct and other times they aren't. This is the code for my function:

```
int *randomizedField(int field[]){
    int temp = 0;
    int random = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(field[i] != '\0'){
        field[i] = field[i] * field[i];
        i++;
    }
    while(field[j] != '\0'){
        random = rand() % i;
        temp = field[j];
        field[j] = field[random];
        field[random] = temp;
        j++;
    }
    return field;
}
```

Comment: Why would an element in an `int` array be equal to a null-terminated string character? You can do all of these operations with STL algorithms, see `std::transform` and `std::shuffle`.

Comment: How are using this function? Please give a [repro] reproducing your problem.

Comment: How do I get the length of the array without having the second parameter? I tried using the sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int) but it gives me a warning.

Comment: @Jamess11 It is impossible to get the length of a raw array argument to a function, because what is passed is actually just a pointer. `int field[]` in a function parameter is exactly the same as `int* field`. That's why you should use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior in your loops:

```
while(field[i] != '\0')
```

You read till you reach a null terminated character. Obviously you never know when you reach that and it won't be end of your array. So you pass the boundaries of your pointer and enter the [undefined bahavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) land.

On the hand you cannot find the size of your array, because when passed to the function the array decays to a pointer and you cannot find its size with `sizeof(field)/sizeof(int)`.

To solve your problem, pass the length of your array to the function or ideally use one of STL containers e.g. [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

The first loop will be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < field.size(); ++i) { 
   field[i] = field[i] * field[i]; 
   i++;
}
```

And the function signature could be:

```
void randomizedField(std::vector<int>& field)
```

Comment: I decided to go with passing the second argument for the length of the array. Thank you very much for you help!